# Formula for Poincare metric on the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H^2}$ denote the open upper half plane in $\mathbb{C}$ and $z$ and  $w$ be any two elements belonging it. The unique circle centered on the real line that passes through both $z$ and $w$ intersects the real line at two points (in case $z$ and $w$ lie on a straight line by abuse of language call the line passing through them as a circle centered on the real line and it intersects the real line at two points , one of which is at $\infty$)  .Of these two points let the one nearer to $z$ be called $z^*$ and the other one be $w^*$ . If $\rho(.,.)$ is the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{H^2}$ then we know that

$$ \rho(z,w) =|\log(z^*,w^*,w,z)|,$$

where $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ is the cross-ratio of the four points.

Now they've given it as as exercise in my book that $\rho$ as above can also be expressed by the formula

$$ \rho(z,w) =\log\frac{|z-\overline{w}|+|z-w|}{|z-\overline{w}|-|z-w|},$$

but I don't know how to prove it. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but I'd assume that you can make heavy use of w.l.o.g. here. If you demonstrate both your formulas to be invariant under hyperbolic isometries i.e. real Möbius transformations, then without loss of generality you can assume your points to be $i$ and $ri$ for some $r\in\mathbb R$ or some similar convenient position.

Comment: Yes @MvG , the idea for proving the first formula was to map this circle to the imaginary axis so that $z^*$ goes to $0$ . But for the second formula I don't know how to apply that idea or substitute $\frac{az+b}{ cz+d}$ and calculate explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to prove $$\frac{|z^*-w|\cdot|w^*-z|}{|w^*-w|\cdot|z^*-z|} = \frac{|z-\overline{w}|+|z-w|}{|z-\overline{w}|\cdot|z-w|}.$$

Note that $z^*,z,w,w^*$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, so Ptolemy implies $(1)$: $$|z^*-w|\cdot|z-w^*| = |z-z^*|\cdot|w-w^*|+|z-w|\cdot|z^*-w^*|.$$

Using this and doing a bit of algebra leads us to want to prove $$2|z-z^*|\cdot|w-w^*| = |z^*-w^*|\cdot|z-\overline{w}|-|z^*-w^*|\cdot|z-w|.$$

Now, the fact that $z^*,z,w^*,\overline{w}$ is a cyclic quadrilateral gives (via Ptolemy) $$|z^*-w^*|\cdot|z-\overline{w}| = |z-z^*|\cdot|w^*-\overline{w}|+|z^*-\overline{w}|\cdot|z-w^*|.$$

So we just wish to prove $$|z-z^*|\cdot|w-w^*| = |z^*-\overline{w}|\cdot|z-w^*|-|z^*-w^*|\cdot|z-w|.$$Now just note $|z^*-\overline{w}| = |z^*-w|$, and so we're done by $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved  [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2354.pdf) for the case that your riemaniann metric slightly changes from $\begin{pmatrix} 1/\sigma^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/\sigma^2 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 1/\sigma^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2/\sigma^2 \end{pmatrix}$. The procedure is with details explained and you should come up with the same result up to some constant multiplication (maybe somewhere a $\sqrt{2}$).